# Website Script that will click on button every x seconds

Tags: ruby, http, curl

Is there an easy way of automating clicking on a certain button on a website?

I'm trying to help someone in my company out, the guy basically stares a booking page the entire day, having to click on a single button to refresh the page. If new booking slots becomes available, then it will only be shown on the page on the page refreshes, which means, the guy needs to click on the button the entire day...

Is there a way of maybe automating this? cUrl? Ruby?

Comment: He needs to be clicking on the refresh button? How often? It is possible to edit the source code of the page, or does it have do be done externally?

Answer (score 4):

If you just refresh the browser to make it refresh then you could try a reload plugin like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115/.  If you actually have to click the button then you could put together a very simple greasemonkey( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/ ) script which just simulates a mouse click.  With jQuery it would be something like

```
$("#buttonid").click()
```

triggered by any one on a hundred timer plugins or setTimout.

Comment: Note: This is a 3rd party website, so I don't have access to the source.

Comment: You can identify the button client-side, so yes you do have access to the source. You just can't alter it. With @stimms answer, you can create a plugin to find the button on the page and trigger it's click event.

Answer (score 1):

First of all i think i have understand your question correctly. What you are trying to do here is that periodically refresh an external web page (say www.google.com)

If so do something like this

create an html page

test.html

and create an iframe inside it and give the url of the web page that you want to refresh

iframe src="http://www.google.com">

and then in the head section add

META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="5"  to refresh the page

Ex:

html

```
<head>
      <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="5"> 
    </head>
    <body>
       <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
    </body>
```

html

Hope you find this helpful (as i said if i understood the question correctly)

cheers
sameera